# Prove $i\lvert z\rvert + 2$ is continuous, using the definition.

Tags: complex-analysis

$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$I know that you have to use the reverse triangle inequality somewhere but I can't quite figure  out where, so far I have that $\abs z= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ 
which leaves, $(i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+ 2)^2$

which leaves $- x^2 - y^2 + 4 $
and when differentiated this leaves, $- 2x$ but I know this isn't right as I don't know how to use the definition with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to prove it is continuous.

Comment: First prove that $z\mapsto |z|$ is continuous. Can you try this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$With $f(z) := i\abs{z} + 2$, we have
$$ \abs{f(z) - f(w)} = \abs{i\abs z  + 2 - i \abs w - 2} = \abs{i}\abs{\abs z - \abs w} = \abs{\abs z - \abs w} $$
Now use the inverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This makes a lot more sense now but I'm still not sure how you use epsilon and delta to prove the function is continuous, do you make up a value for delta?